# EF code first update entity with its children

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I got update method that updates only the entity without its children

```
    public void Update(T obj)
    {
        Ensure.IsNull(obj);

        using (var DB = AccessManager.db)
        {
            DB.Set<T>().Attach(obj);
            DB.Entry(obj).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            DB.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I try to update

```
LessonModel.Title = "Updated";
LessonModel.Files.Add(new LessonFileModel { IdxNumber = LessonModel.IdxNumber, FileName = "asd", FilePath = " asdf" });
DALFacade.Lesson.Update(LessonModel);
```

Only the title gets updated. The files are not updated.

So if the method like this:

```
    public void Update(LessonModel obj)
    {
        Ensure.IsNull(obj);

        using (var DB = AccessManager.db)
        {
            DB.Lessons.Attach(obj);
            DB.Entry(obj).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            DB.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

How can i save the child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the problems that arise when you use the ["Generic Repository" anti pattern](http://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern). Writing an Update method that works for every combination of entity graphs that you pass in and will always do exactly what you want it to do is a big *pain in the EF*.

Instead, try writing repositories that match your use cases.

Your current problem could be solved if you added the files to the lesson *after* you attached it to the context. Marking an entry as modified marks all properties on this entry as modified, it doesn't affect relationships.

Comment: And if I do it match repository how can i update the child too?

Comment: You could iterate over the files and attach them too.